# <select multiple> </select> set more values with val() method in jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, servlets, jstl

**My jsp page**

```
<script type="application/javascript">
   <c:forEach var="bs" items="${subjectOfBookList}">
        $("#bSubjectU").val(${bs.subjects.id});
    </c:forEach>
</script>


  <select id="bSubjectU" multiple style="height: 150px">
        <option value="0">Select Subjects</option>
        <c:forEach var="sl" items="${subjectList}">
            <option value="${sl.id}">${sl.subjectName}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

*where **${subjectOfBookList}** return my servlet. How i set all list items in select(multiple) element. Now i just get last value. I checked all values return, but set last value.* Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push value from `<c:forEach` in js array then use that array to set mutliple value selected inside your dropdown.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var arrys = ["1", "2"]
$("#bSubjectU").val(arrys);
//uncomment to use below
//var arr =[]
// <c:forEach var="bs" items="${subjectOfBookList}">
//push that value inside arr
//arr.push("${bs.subjects.id}")
//</c:forEach>
//$("#bSubjectU").val(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="bSubjectU" multiple style="height: 150px">
  <option value="0">Select Subjects</option>
  <option value="1">A</option>
  <option value="2">B</option>
  <option value="3">C</option>
</select>
```